# tcsh 'ls_colors' not working

Tags: tcsh, ls-colors

I am using tcsh as my default shell. However, the LS_COLORS env doesn't seem to work. Here is my related env for ls:

```
setenv CLICOLOR "true"
setenv LS_COLORS "di=37:fi=00"
```

Directories are suposed to be coloured white, but the result is they are coloured blue/cyan. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem. I am required to use tcsh and xterm. I also didn't have luck with setenv CLICOLOR.

try:

```
alias ls ls --color=always
```

source: [ls man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)

Answer (score 2):

[This thread on the web](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=28541) might help on the syntax of `LS_COLORS` in general.

In your particular case it looks ok. Did you `set color` in your shell?